# Azure logic apps: Only attach file if condition met outlook v2

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-logic-apps, email-attachments

I am creating an automated email that sends everyday on a schedule. Within this 4 reports are created using individual sql queries that then generate csv files with essentially a list of names - all this works fine. When some of these are generated they are empty so I have used parallel branches to set a variable to true or false if the csv is created or not.

So at the end of this I have 3/4 files and a variable for each stating whether or not it has been created.

What I want to know is how do I only attach a file if a variable is true as if a null/not created csv is attached it errors.

Any additional information required just ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is how do I only attach a file if a variable is true as if a null/not created csv is attached it errors.

When you use parallel branches, each branch is executed regardless of whether the variable is true/false or if the file is created/not. In this case, you can use the `Condition` action instead of parallel branches where the email is sent only when the variable is true. Below is the flow of my Logic app.

[image]